# Angular2 - pass value to parent/child component

Tags: angular, parameters

I need to pass a parameter or to modify an exposed property on a component given this app.component structure:

## app.component.html

```
<app-appheader></app-appheader>
<app-appmenu></app-appmenu>
<div class="main-container">    
    <router-outlet>
        <span *ngIf="showLoader" class="loading"></span>
    </router-outlet>    
</div>
<app-appfooter></app-appfooter>
```

In detail, I need to pass a parameter **to app-appmenu** component from the component loaded in router-outlet...

I don'w know what are the steps in order to do it.

Thanks to support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several ways to pass data from components.

In the documentation ([this link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)) you'll find them, but I suggest you to use a [shared service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).

The structure would be somewhat this:

1. Component A has data. Calls Shared Service.
2. Component B is subscribed to the method of Shared Service, as soon as Component A calls it, Component B *"requests to Shared Service the data"*.
3. Shared Service returns the data from its method to all subscribed components (of the method), therefore, returns data to Component B.

See the Shared Service as a *middleman* between components.

It doesn't take into consideration the level of the components (child, parent, grand parent, etc.). It works with call method/trigger subscriptions.